# How can I deactivate the steam url filter?

Tags: steam

If I open a link through the steam chat fenster a what I call URL-Filter appears. It notice you that you are leaving the offical steam sites.

I really want to remove that. I know myself when I leave steam and I also know how to recognize phishing sites.

I added here a image of the site I mean:

[image: Example]

How can I remove that screen? Keep in mind that I do not really want to install any software, plugins or other strange tools to remove that!

Are there several solutions?

Comment: This has been in place for well over a year if not longer, not just a few weeks.

Comment: @Aravona Are you sure? To me this is pretty new... Well I don't know and it also doesen't matter in the context of my question.

Comment: @Aravona A year?  I doubt it, otherwise people on Reddit's /r/tf2 wouldn't have been constantly complaining about phishing attacks up until just recently.

Comment: I've started seeing this in the last month, before that I'd never had this message. Perhaps it's been around for years for some group of users, but has only just rolled out to everyone?

Comment: Oh so I wasn't wrong? Thx Powerlord and DBS...

Comment: @DBS might be right in that it is for a select group until recently. Steam has recently had a massive update so might be that, but I, my fiance and most of my friends on Steam have definitely had the Steam 'this is not a steam url' check for ages. I've used Steam for three or more years and always had it. Perhaps it is because of a select group, country etc. I don't know, but for some people this is very old! I will state I don't use the browser to use Steam so that maybe newer but Steam chat always for me had the checks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without any software or plugins, it is not possible to circumvent this. Steam does not provide any option to do so.

However, you can use this Grease Monkey Script to bypass it:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Steam Linkfilter Bypass
// @version    0.1
// @description  Bypasses the steam link filter
// @match      https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/*
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var URL = document.URL;
var str = URL.split("url=");
window.location = str[1];
```

[Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) is an addon for Firefox, that lets you modify the contents of any webpage with the help of [Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). On [Chrome](http://techsupportguides.com/install-userscripts-in-chrome/), it is called [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) and maintained by a different developer.

Comment: Could you explain what a greasemonkey script is?

Comment: @Gerret Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answer using greasemonkey, you can use a browser plugin called redirector available for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redirector/ocgpenflpmgnfapjedencafcfakcekcd?hl=en-US).

You will need to open the redirector menu, select edit redirects, and then make a new redirect.

You'll fill in the fields like so:

```
Description: skip steam's link filter
Example URL: https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?url=https://forums.factorio.com/61015
Include pattern: https://steamcommunity.com/linkfilter/?url=*
Redirect to: $1
Pattern type: wildcard
```

You don't have to use my description or example URL, but it won't hurt anything if you do.

After creating your redirect, anytime you click an external link with steam, it will automatically redirect from steam's link filter to the site you wanted.

You can also bypass the link filter if you use the [Enhanced Steam](http://www.enhancedsteam.com/) plugin by going to options, selecting community, then checking "Disable confirmation when accessing external sites"